# project build and run issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

While build and run the project, I got a pop up Debugging not enabled.

It shows, the page cannot be run in debug mode because debugging is not enabled in web.config

while selecting Run without debugging , it shows Unable to launch because port is in use.
but i am trying to resolving it by selecting, Use IIS Web server,i got a pop up, you need to configure the virtual directory,.

Please help us.

Now this time build and run made successful but page shows blank .please advice us

Answer (score 0):

Look in your web.config file. Do a CTRL+F for "debugging". There is a simple XML entry that is called DebuggingEnabled or something along those lines. It is set to false by default, so just set it to true, save your project and retry.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Now it shows blank page while running.

Comment: Create a .html page, type Hello world in the page and save it. Try accessing that page from your browser. If you see the text then the issue is with your code.

Comment: as per your advice, i have tried the HTML pages it is working fine. May be issues with my code. One more clarification, while running the project also one pop up appear in the name ASP.net development server, and shows error An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. Please advice us

Comment: Are you running the page through debug mode, or by opening the actual file? ASP.NET requires that the code be passed through a server. If you simply opened the .ASPX with your browser without passing through a local development server then the page will very likely be blank.